"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array" when creating an OnlineMeeting with Microsoft Graph SDK
I am trying to use the Graph SDK to create Online Meetings.
public WrapperVO<Object> generateTeamsUrl(MultipartFormDataInput dates) throws BusinessException, TechnicalException{
    WrapperVO<Object> wVO = new WrapperVO<Object>();
    String[] scopes = new String[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    String clientSecret = //in database
    String meetingStart = null;
    String meetingEnd = null;
    try {
       meetingStart = dates.getFormDataPart("meetingStart", String.class, null);
       meetingEnd = dates.getFormDataPart("meetingEnd", String.class, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("")
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId("")
            .build();
    
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    OnlineMeeting onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting();
    onlineMeeting.setStartDateTime(OffsetDateTime.parse(meetingStart));
    onlineMeeting.setEndDateTime(OffsetDateTime.parse(meetingEnd));
    onlineMeeting.setSubject("Meeting");
    OnlineMeeting createdMeeting = graphClient.users().byUserId("").onlineMeetings()
          .post(onlineMeeting);
    System.out.println("OnlineMeeting URL: " + createdMeeting.getJoinWebUrl());
    
    Response resp = Response.ok(createdMeeting.getJoinWebUrl()).build();
    return new WrapperVO<>(wVO.addData(resp), new MetaDataVO());
   }

Using this code, i have the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('')/onlineMeetings/$entity","id":"","creationDateTime":"2024-04-15T11:23:24.1567614Z","startDateTime":"2024-04-16T10:11:00Z","endDateTime":"2024-04-16T11:11:00Z","joinUrl":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_MjgyY2Y","meetingCode":"","isBroadcast":false,"autoAdmittedUsers":"everyoneInCompany","outerMeetingAutoAdmittedUsers":null,"capabilities":[],"externalId":null,"iCalUid":null,"meetingType":null,"meetingsMigrationMode":null,"joinWebUrl":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_","subject":"Meeting","videoTeleconferenceId":null,"isEntryExitAnnounced":true,"allowedPresenters":"everyone","allowAttendeeToEnableMic":true,"allowAttendeeToEnableCamera":true,"allowMeetingChat":"enabled","shareMeetingChatHistoryDefault":"none","allowTeamworkReactions":true,"anonymizeIdentityForRoles":[],"recordAutomatically":false,"allowParticipantsToChangeName":false,"allowTranscription":true,"allowRecording":true,"meetingTemplateId":null,"broadcastSettings":null,"meetingInfo":null,"audioConferencing":null,"watermarkProtection":null,"chatRestrictions":null,"participants":{"organizer":{"upn":"","role":"presenter","identity":{"application":null,"device":null,"user":{"id":"","displayName":null,"tenantId":"","identityProvider":"AAD"}}},"attendees":[]},"chatInfo":{"threadId":"19:meeting_","messageId":"0","replyChainMessageId":null},"joinInformation":{"content":"data:text/html","contentType":"html"},"joinMeetingIdSettings":{"isPasscodeRequired":false,"joinMeetingId":"38","passcode":null},"lobbyBypassSettings":{"scope":"organization","isDialInBypassEnabled":false}} at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:117) at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.iterateOnArray(JsonParseNode.java:167) at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getUntypedValue(JsonParseNode.java:245) at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.tryGetAnything(JsonParseNode.java:317) at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.assignFieldValues(JsonParseNode.java:299) at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:213) at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.send(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:296) at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.onlinemeetings.OnlineMeetingsRequestBuilder.post(OnlineMeetingsRequestBuilder.java:120)

Can you help me with this issue please ?
I have tried upgrading some of the dependencies i am using, mostly jackson-core and other related dependencies.

JSON objects are wrapped with "{ }" while JSON Arrays are wrapped with "[ ]". Not sure from your code where all of this is done. But in your error I can see you are using "getAsJsonArray" which is trying to get your data as JSON Array while it is actually a JSON Object. You would have to use "getAsJsonObject"
